# Excel: Multiple MATCH Criteria (with an IF thrown in)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

I need to calculate the Overall Score for each row of Table3 in the following manner:

1. Take the `Round` number and `Pair` name from `Table3` and find the corresponding row from `Table1` which matches both. Take the `Score` value. (For example, for row 5 of `Table3`, it is the third row of `Table1`.) However, if the Pair is listed in column `Pair2`, then take the Score with the +/- sign inverted. (For example, for row 3 of `Table3`, it will be the first row of `Table1`, but the value we get shall be `-5`.) Let us call this **Value1**.
2. Match the `Round` number of the row (from `Table3`) with the `Round` number from `Table2` and get the `Score Average` value. Let us call this **Value2**.
3. The `Overall Score` for that row is `Value1 - Value2`.

Example: For row three: B1's Overall Score at row 3 is: -5-(-1.25)=-3.75

**How do I combine multiple MATCH criteria and take care of the IF condition along the way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done with just `MATCH()` and `IF()`. You need to use a formula using arrays.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the follow formula in the range `K3:K26`:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Score]*(Table3[[#This Row],[Round]]=Table1[Round])*(Table3[[#This Row],[Pair]]=Table1[Pair1])-Table1[Score]*(Table3[[#This Row],[Round]]=Table1[Round])*(Table3[[#This Row],[Pair]]=Table1[Pair2]))-INDEX(Table2[Score Average],MATCH(Table3[[#This Row],[Round]],Table2[Round],0))
```

The above formula will work on Excel 2007+. The following easier to read version works for Excel 2010+:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Score]*([@[Round]]=Table1[Round])*([@[Pair]]=Table1[Pair1])-Table1[Score]*([@[Round]]=Table1[Round])*([@[Pair]]=Table1[Pair2]))-INDEX(Table2[Score Average],MATCH([@[Round]],Table2[Round],0))
```

---

The prettified formula is as follows:

```dart
=
SUMPRODUCT(
  Table1[Score]*([@[Round]]=Table1[Round])*([@[Pair]]=Table1[Pair1])
  -Table1[Score]*([@[Round]]=Table1[Round])*([@[Pair]]=Table1[Pair2])
  )
-INDEX(Table2[Score Average],MATCH([@[Round]],Table2[Round],0))
```